# Passing location props to page generates build error - Link Component - Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Reading the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/) I discovered that Gatsby has built-in feature to pass props a to page within its Link Component using the `state` prop. In development environment everything works as expected and any page is always rendered properly with passed props when navigating from the component below. However during the build I get an error `Building static HTML failed for path "/page/", WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'access' of undefined`, same happens for any `location.state` called inside that page.

**Link Component**

```
const data = { 
  title: "Hello Guys",
  date: "23 November 2020"
}

<Link
  to="/form"
  state={{
    access: true,
    title: data.title,
    date: data.date
  }}
  > Proceed
</Link>
```

**Page**

```
const Page = ( { location } ) => {

 
    if (location.state.access === true) {
    
    return (
        <>
            <div>{location.state.title}</div>
            <div>{location.state.date}</div>
        </>
    )}

    else {
        return <div>Nada</div>
    }           
}

export default Page
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue appears because you are not providing `location` (hence not `state` or `access` properties) in all calls of `Page` component so the compilation fails.

Add a condition such:

```
const Page = ( { location } ) => {

 
    if (location && location.state && location.state.access) {
    
    return (
        <>
            <div>{location.state.title}</div>
            <div>{location.state.date}</div>
        </>
    )}

    else {
        return <div>Nada</div>
    }           
}

export default Page
```

If you are using the [Optional Chaining Proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) you just can:

```
if (location?.state?.access) {...}
```

You can also set as default the `location` in the `props` destructuring like:

```
const Page = ( { location = {} } ) => {}
```

So, if you are not sending it, it will result as an empty object (`{}`), so without any `state` property inside.

Comment: Thank you Ferran, I also managed to build and render with just `if (location.state)`, but I have a clarification to ask, when I declare `{location}` as parameter of Page shouldn't it import the entire object with all its properties? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it does. But if you don't have a `location` to "import" it results undefined. What you can do is to set as default the location like `{location={}}` so if you are not passing it it will result as an empty object (without `state`)